# Union of two sets in tripartition of an open ball contains another open ball

Tags: general-topology

**Claim.** Let $B$ be an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $X,Y,Z\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be non-empty, open and disjoint such that $B$ is the interior of ${cl}(X\cup Y\cup Z)$. Then, there exists an open ball $B'\subset B$ such that $B'\not\subset X,Y,Z$ and $B'\subset {cl}(X\cup Z)$ or $B'\subset {cl}(Y\cup Z)$.

I cannot come up with a proof for this seemingly obvious claim. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is false. Now if you added simply connected to the properties of $X, Y, Z$, then it might be true.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Do you have an idea for a counterexample? Also, do you have an intuition for why simple connectedness may suffice but connectedness may not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $d = 2$. Let $B$ be the open unit disk about the origin.

- Let $U_1$ be the union of two disjoint open disks of radius $\frac 12$ inside $B$.
- In each component of $B \setminus \overline U_1$, put an open disk of maximal radius. Let $U_2$ be the union of these disks.
- In each component of $B \setminus \overline {U_1 \cup U_2}$, put an open disk of maximal radius. Let $U_3$ be the union of these disks.
- Etc.

Let $X = \bigcup_k U_{1+3k}, Y = \bigcup_k U_{2+3k}, Z=\bigcup_k U_{3+3k}$. Any neighborhood of a point of $B\setminus X\cup Y\cup Z$ will intersect all three of them.

Connectedness might be enough to avoid this problem in $\Bbb R^2$ (I haven't thought it out, so it may not be enough even there), but in $\Bbb R^3$, you can exploit the other dimension to connect all the pieces of $X, Y, Z$, without breaking the intermingling.

You can also do something similar in $\Bbb R$. You just have to be more artificial about leaving holes to be filled later. But in $\Bbb R$, connectedness is definitely sufficient to prove your result.

Comment: This is an elegant counterexample. I don't yet see how I would be able to connect the balls in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in a similar construction but I will ponder this some more. Hopefully, this will make me realize what additional assumptions would be needed.

Comment: In 3D you don't get disconnected components, but you can still fill in spheres in groups so that all three sets have spheres in each region. Because the remaining space isn't disconnected, you can run thin tubes through it from each new sphere back to another sphere in the same set. These tubes force later spheres to be smaller to fit in the open space, but in the infinite limit, you can still fill the entire original ball with their closures.

Comment: FYI - having thought about my description in the previous comment, the spheres in each set would form the vertices of a tree graph with the tubes as edges. Trees have no loops, so the final result of this process would be that $X, Y, Z$ are all contractable, and therefore simply connected. I.e., simple connectedness, or even contractability, is not enough to prove your theorem when $d \ge 3$.